# Pass a variable by reference from Angular2 template

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a variable called isVisible. And I have a method called

```
ReverseVariable(variable: boolean)
{
   variable = !variable;
}
```

I want to call this method from a template like

```
<button (click)="ReverseVariable(isVisible)"></button>
```

I want to give it isVisible in the parameters and have isVisible reverse itself. Something like the following example is not an option

```
ReverseVisibility()
{
  this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
}
```

Is there any way that I can pass the variable by reference?

Comment: Is `isVisible` a property of the component? Do you say that `this.isVisible = !this.isVisible` is not an option because the variable name needs to be dynamic or because the variable doesn't belong to the `this` context?

Comment: It's not an option because I have way too many isVisible variables and with my last example, I will need a method for every one of them which is not great. It only clutters my component.

Comment: Ok. Are the variables properties of the component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with a primitive data type like a boolean. What you could do is make a non-primitive like an object

```
isVisible = {
    flag: true
}
```

Then toggle that in your function

```
ReverseVisibility(isVisible)
{
   isVisible.flag = !isVisible.flag;
}
```

Here is plnkr demonstrating this (https://plnkr.co/edit/VYEimNoHZvGxeE4S2W4L?p=preview)